# How much damage can SQL injection do via this stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, security, stored-procedures, sql-injection

Recently chanced upon a stored procedure hardcoded by predecessors to perform some CRUD. It affects non-critical tables in production database. I feel like it's vulnerable to SQL injection but seems like the injection is really harmless as it's performing CRUD on non-critical tables.

The @LocalDatabase parameter is passed in from the `connectionString="Server=localHost;Database=localDatabase;..."` in config file.

I was wondering if a possible SQL injection in this specific SP can catastrophically harm the production database? I'm weighing the cost-benefit of rewriting this whole module.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE StoredProc_Name
(
    @LocalDatabase      varchar(50),
    @Result             int             OUTPUT
)

SET @Sql = N'UPDATE <Production Database>.Table1
SET     ...
FROM    <Production Database>.NewTable INNER JOIN
        '+ @LocalDatabase +'.dbo.Table1 ON ... INNER JOIN
        '+ @LocalDatabase +'.dbo.Table2 ON ...
WHERE   NOT EXISTS(SELECT   1
                    FROM    <Production Database>.dbo.Table2
                    WHERE   .....)'

EXEC(@Sql)
SET @Result = @@ROWCOUNT
```

Appreciate any advice or help in pointing in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regardless of the SQL injection threat ... this is really bad practice, i highly recommend you redoing this code.

Comment: @SufyanJabr why is it so? May I have some insights so I can better justify my case to rewrite the module? Ya know... 'It does get the job done' argument.

Comment: Am not aware of the exact case that you have, but using Exec by concatenating the SQL is one of the really bad practices and it need to be avoided.

From what i can see is that you trying to switch databases based on the parameter, why don't you do it on the connection string ?

Comment: @SufyanJabr the exact use case would be to sync the 'central' database with the latest records from local databases. So each local database will update the records in the central db by running this stored proc. Have since read about concatenating SQL/SQL injection since your last reply. Thank you for your insights. Will rewrite this module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the user isn't affecting the value passed in as @LocalDatabase, this approach would be OK.  Not using dynamic SQL would be better, but this approach can work...

Comment: thank you but may I ask whether the design is good practice and why yes or why not?

Comment: Well: generally avoiding dynamic SQL is recommended when possible.  I don't think it's possible to change databases for a query dynamically, so the only alternative is to create a copy of that query for each database in a large if/else statement.  That's the same query many times, so that doesn't really help maintaining it in the future.  So I'd say, because of the ease of maintenance and as long as it doesn't result in terrible performance, I'd let this one stay just for the maintenance aspect.